# $\mathbb{S}:=\{(-\infty,b):b \in \mathbb{Q}\} \cup \{(a,\infty):b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a subbase

Tags: general-topology

Exercise:
Show that in $\mathbb{R}$ the Set $\mathbb{S}:=\{(-\infty,b):b \in \mathbb{Q}\} \cup \{(a,\infty):b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a subbase.

My Approach:
So i need to show that $B:=\{\bigcap_{S \in F}S:F \subseteq S, F \text{ finite}\}$ is a Base for the euclidean topology

I know that

$$\tag 1 B \text{ is base for } \tau \Leftrightarrow \forall T \in \tau \forall x \in T \exists V \in B:x \in V \subseteq T$$

So, let $T$ be in $\tau$ and $x$ in $T.$
Because $T$ is open, it can be written as $T=(c,d)$ with $c,d \in \mathbb{R} \cup\{-\infty\}\cup\{\infty\}$

If $c$ is $-\infty$ ,the set $(-\infty,r)$ whre $d<r \in \mathbb{Q}$ is in $B$
and the left of the equivalence in (1) holds
If $d$ is $\infty$ ,the set $(r,\infty)$ whre $c>r \in \mathbb{Q}$ is in $B$
and the left of the equivalence in (1) holds
If $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ then the Intervall $(r,R)$ where $r<c$ and $d<R$  and $r,R \in \mathbb{Q}$ also statisfies the condition in (1)

My Question is:
Is my approach right? In the Definition of S, is there something special about $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$ or
could S be defined using any not-bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so that it is still a subbase?

Comment: You need also that the rational numbers are dense, so  you can approximate arbitrary Intervall boundaries. So thus works for every dense subset. As an example: the Natural Numbers are an unbounded subset but the construction would not yield a subbase.

Comment: Whoops, after Reading again, there is one caveat to Your reasoning: not every Open Set in the reals is an intervall. However, every open Set in the reals is a (possible Infinite) union of Open intervals the approach still holds Up.

Comment: I don't see why the set needs to be dense. If i take the Integers, it should work too.

Comment: How do you generate the Open Set $(\pi, \pi+1/2)$ If all you have is intersections of $(-\infty,N) $ and $(m, \infty)$ for $N,m$ natural numbers??

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. In particular the whole of the expression $$\mathbb{S}:=\{(-\infty,b):b \in \mathbb{Q}\} \cup \{(a,\infty):b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$ should be between just one pair of dollar signs or double dollar signs, and the phrase "let $T$ be in", etc., should use MathJax. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you, i will have a look

Comment: @AlexanderSchmeding Why would I need to generate an open set. I think I only need a open subset of it. BUt I got your point, with Integers one can not get a subset of every open set.

Comment: A subbase gives You a base by considering all finite intersections of ist Elements. For a base  every element of an Open Set there is a basic neighborhood containing the element and being itself contained in the given Open Set. This is  why i am thinking about generating sets. It boils doen to writing every open Set as the .union of all basic neighborhoods contained in it.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmeding thank you, this was very helpful